# How to change 'card' in Jframe cardlayout from Jpanel which belonging to card and its placed in another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, cardlayout

I have written a jframe with cardlayout as in the following code :

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {


private static CardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();
   private static JPanel cards = new JPanel(cardlayout);

public Gui() {

cards.setLayout(cardlayout);
CasaPanel card =new CasaPanel();
cards.add(card,"casa");
InCash card_1 = new InCash();
cards.add(card_1,"in");
OutCash card_2 = new OutCash();
cards.add(card_2,"out");
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void showCard(String name)
{
    cardlayout.show(cards, name);
}
```

i'm trying to call method to change card (ShowCard) from one of the JPanel(CasaPanel) , which is itself a 'card'. I want change a 'card' after clicking a button in a JPanel(CasaPanel) which is in another class. How to do this?I mean i know how to add button and listener but i don't know if is it possible to call a method in JFrame from a Jpanel class belonging to that frame ? How to refer to method in JFrame from  other classes? I looked at  [this](http:////stackoverflow.com/questions/13913473/i-cant-change-card-in-cardlayout-using-jtree-listener) question but i really don't want  put all code in one class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "card" is added to the panel which uses the `CardLayout`. If you want to change cards then you just need access to the layout mananger. So from your panel you can use the getParent() method to get the parent panel and then use the getLayout() method to get the CardLayout.

So the code in the ActionListener might be something like:

```
JPanel parent = (JPanel)getParent();
CardLayout layout = parent.getLayout();
layout.show(panel, "...");
```

Also, then general design on your class is wrong. You should NOT be using static methods. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for working examples and a better way to structure your code.

Comment: Thank a lot for working solution and tip how to better structure this class.